# A smart way to drag html structure

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Consider the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2LyWt/8/

I´m trying to move the whole accordion item instead of just the test.
I guess the solution is hidden somewhere on the line of

```
$( "<div></div>" ).text( ui.draggable.text() ).appendTo( this );
```

Is there a way to grab the html-structure so that the whole accordion-element will be dropped and not just the text?

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
$( "<div></div>" ).html( ui.draggable.html() ).appendTo( this );
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2LyWt/9/) ?

Comment: Quite next to excellent, thank you. 
I guess I have to make the cart an accordion to collapse items?

Comment: Somehow just making it an accordion doesn´t fix it. It seems the ui.draggable.html is just appending what is visual, is that so?
http://jsfiddle.net/2LyWt/11/

Answer (score 1):

You want to grab the whole accordion to be dragged then you need to applied it on the accordion container i.e. `#products`, so just change the element on which `draggable()` function applied.

```
$( ".category" ).draggable({...});
```

to

```
$( "#products" ).draggable({
  appendTo: "body",
  helper: "clone"
});
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2LyWt/10/)

Comment: I think he just wants the menus not the whole products div. Just T-shirts, bags or gadgets should be dragged in

Comment: @Kierchon if you see his initial fiddle these headers are already being dragged. So don't think so.

Comment: I know they are being dragged but when you drop them they disappear I think he wants them to show up where you drop them. Not just the inner text